# Delayed printing within a whole program

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I want every message in my program to be printed with a small delay between each character.

I can use

```
import time

string = "hello world"
for char in string:
   print(char, end='')
   time.sleep(.25)
```

to do that for a single string. I can extrapolate that to a class using a __print__ method, but that still requires me to use a class each time I want to use my edited print method. How can I add delay to every character printed for the entire program so that I can use `print("foo")` anywhere and expect it to work as intended?

Comment: best is to write another function and pass that message to that function and then delay print it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you can do is create a function for this, i.e:

```
def print_delayed(string):
    for char in string:
       builtins.print(char, end='', flush=True) # flush gets the actual delay, otherwise
                                                # the text is printed after all the sleeps
       time.sleep(.25)
```

Then, you can set `print` equal to this function, i.e:

```
print = print_delayed
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing this; just call the new function you have made, instead of overriding built-in ones.

Here is a [working example](https://repl.it/repls/HarmlessDirtyAstronomy).

Answer (score 1):

as Albin said in comments it is better to create a function and call it instead of `print` like this:

```
def delayed_print(v, *args, **kwargs):
    print(v,*args, **kwargs)
    time.sleep(.25)

string = "hello world"
for char in string:
    delayed_print(char, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the `print` function like this:

```
import builtins
import time

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    for char in args[0]:
        builtins.print(char, end='')
        time.sleep(.25)
```

This will overload the function at the module level.

Answer (score 0):

You can override print:

```
import time
import sys

string = "hello world"

def print(x):
    for char in x:
      sys.stdout.write(char)
      time.sleep(.25)
    sys.stdout.write('\n')

print(string)
```

Will get you what you want.